# Creating a bootable dvd disk with Windows

Tags: 13.04, live-usb, dvd

I want to install Windows 7 from Ubuntu. I know it's tricky but nonetheless I need it. How do I create a bootable dvd disk with Windows then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu comes along with an ISO Burner. I don't know the English name of the program, but the icon of it is an Ubuntu logo and an arrow pointing at a disc drive
If you have a Win7 ISO, you can burn it using this program. If not, you need to download the one you need (I hope you got a valid license). [Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/wo-kann-ich-die-windows-7-iso-dateien/610a3a3c-e99c-42e6-8cf8-fda31127b035) are the links to various Win7 versions in German and English (German site, sorry)

Comment: startup disk creator can only be used for creating ubuntu bootable disk or usb.

Comment: OK thanks for this information. Brasero (which comes along with ubuntu) should also be able to burn images

Comment: but can it create a bootable disk? not just burn iso to it.

Comment: It depends on the ISO whether the DVD will be bootable or not. An ISO file is nothing else than a virtual 1:1 copy of the DVD.